# How to select a radio value using espresso web

Tags: android, android-espresso

In my Android project, I have a webview. HTML source has 2 radio buttons. Using Espresso Web, I want to choose one of these 2. How do I do that?

For eg:

```
<input type="radio" value="City A" name="Location" id="Location">
<input type="radio" value="City B" name="Location" id="Location">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add espresso-web to your test project (see https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/web/ and follow the instructions to make sure JavaScript is enabled on your WebView):

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2'
```

Then one way you can perform actions on the radio buttons is using a CSS selector like so:

```
onWebView()
  .withElement(findElement(Locator.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value=\"City B\"]"))
  .perform(webClick());
```

If your radio buttons had unique IDs (like they should have), you can also select by ID:

```
.withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "Location2"))
```

See this https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/espresso/WebBasicSample sample project where you can see the full working set up and easily try out different HTML code and selectors.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot